# Does the most current version of flame support null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, game-engine, flame, pubspec

I am pretty new to the flame game engine but whenever I try to run my program it keeps saying that

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:flame
- package:ordered_set
- package:box2d_flame

I am just wondering if maybe I am not using the most current version of flame or if I need to temporarily disable null safety? Here is what my pubspec.yaml file currently looks like.

```
name: first_game
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  flame: ^0.29.4


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
     - assets/images/terrythemale.png
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the current stable version, our newest version is `1.0.0-rc10` and in that one we do support null-safety (this is the version that all of our docs are for too).

Do note however that pub counts `rc10` as smaller than `rc9`, so you have to skip the `^` in your pubspec file and depend specifically on `rc10` like this:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  flame: 1.0.0-rc10
```

We will most likely release rc11 later today which won't have this problem.

EDIT: `rc11` is now released so now you can use `^` again:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  flame: "^1.0.0-releasecandidate.11"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pubspec from the version you are using: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/0.29.3/pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.6.0"
```

The answer is no. But there are a release candidate version (latest 1.0.0-rc10) which seems to support null safety: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/1.0.0-rc10/packages/flame/pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.24.0"
```

So you can either wait for "1.0.0" to be released or use the release candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error and also I was unable to find the mention of sound null safety in the release documentation of flame v0.29.4 I think its still not migrated to null safety.

your min sdk version in pubspec.yaml is 2.12 which makes your app use sound null safety by default so to build the project use flag --no-sound-null-safety with flutter /dart commands  Eg. "$ flutter run --no-sound-null-safety" . and for more info visit https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety.

Answer (score 0):

**Migrate your flutter dart package because everything is now about the null safety**

So after updating of flutter(version sdk 2.0.2) it allows only null safety plugin .

Follow these migration commands one by one.

**Step 1)**

> `dart migrate`

If your migrate is fail. So, there will be some reasons behind that like,
some flutter plugins are not upgraded.
or else somewhere some plugin is dependent on some other no null safety plugin.

**Step 2)**

> `flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety`

By using this command you can see latest package version/ Plugin with null safety. From here you can update plugin versions.

**Step 3)** again run this command

> `dart migrate`

**Step 4)**

> `flutter pub upgrade`

**Step 5)**

> `flutter pub get`

**Step 6)**

> `flutter run`

**`Using this link more idea`**

https://youtu.be/eBr5tlumwlg